# Getting data from database if two more than one record is present

Tags: java, android, database, servlets, resultset

I'm developing an application in which I pick rcode(numbers) from the database with the name. If the name is present it will display the rcode associated with it. The output like

```
10001
```

Suppose, if two names are present with the same name, it will display like

```
10001 10002
```

Here is my servlet code for this..

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from newfarmer where rname='"+get+"'");
while(rs.next()){
    username=rs.getString("rname");

    if(get.equals(username)){
        rcode=rs.getString("rcode");
        out.println(rcode);
    }
}
```

and,
I'm using the following code in my android application to get the data from it. That is I need to pick all the data something like where rname=" ". Now the problem is if two records with the same name are present, It will pickup only one record. But servlet outputs show as

```
10001 10002
```

In my application I count the total number of records and display it. But it shows only one

```
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line);
    count=st.countTokens();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), count+" names found", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    r_code=st.nextToken();
    ff=1;
}
```

So, I need to access both the records and also count the total no.of records. Can anyone help to do this

Comment: in this at which basis you are using StringTokenizer as there is no delimeter

Comment: also if you have fetch only records where rname = get then why to check if (get.equals(username))

Comment: Oh I understood now. Thanks, I'll correct it. But how to solve count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`out.println(rcode)` adds a CRLF (which is ignored when you look at the output with a browser). What happens if you replace it with a space character ?

```
out.print(rcode);
out.print(" ");
```

Comment: but `line = reader.readLine()` should now read 1 line containing 2 tokens instead of 2 lines containing 1 token each, so `st.countTokens()` should now return 2

Comment: Oh yes. I'll try this and tell

Comment: Now it display 2 items. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use list to display the records and add one counter....,for list refer http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Ok, but the count is actually displayed as 1 always.

Comment: make sure that count is getting updated and not initialized as 1 again and again..after a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

i am not able to understand why you are writting that inside if statement. you need not to write that statement as username will always be equal to get.  remove that statement and try to run it again.